# Running Robot Tests with Phantom JS

Tags: phantomjs, robotframework

Can someone please tell how to run Robot Tests with Phantom JS?

I have written few Robot tests. I was able to run successfully with different browsers (ie, ff, Chrome).
I want the same to run with Phantom JS (Headless browser). For this, I gave 'phantomjs' for "browser" argument just like below (sample robot script).

```
*** Settings ***
Library           C:/python27/lib/site-packages/Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Test
Open Browser    http://example.com   phantomjs
Log Source    INFO
```

But getting below error.

> WebDriverException: Message: 'Unable to start phantomjs with
>   ghostdriver.' ; Screenshot: available via screen

Someone please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have PhantomJS executable downloaded and added into PATH. I use the below method specifically to handle the PhantomJS browser to open:

```
Create Webdriver  PhantomJS
Go To  http://account.netzero.net
```

I'm sure it will work if you have the PhantomJS in the PATH env.

Comment: thanks Vimal! Now seeing error as below Message: WebDriverException: Message: 'Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.' ; Screenshot: available via screen

Comment: Could ulyou pls tell me what output you are getting when you execute 'phantomjs' command from command prompt/terminal?